# I want to know which image is pressed in UIScrollView in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have `UIScrollView` that consists of `UIImageView`s. When I touch any `imageView`, I want to display this `UIImageView`'s `image` in other window. how can I do that? any ideas .

I use `UITapGestureRecognizer` but I cant find which `imageView` is pressed.

this is my code:

```
for (NSArray *photo in self.photos) {
        imageName = [photo valueForKey:@"filename"];
        imageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

        UIImageView *imageView;
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(imageX, imageY, imageSize, imageSize)];

        imageX += imageSize + 10;
        if (imageX + imageSize >= self.view.bounds.size.width){
            imageX = 15;
            imageY += imageSize + 10;
        }

        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(goFullPhotoGallery:)];
        [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    }
```

Comment: In `goFullPhotoGallery:`, the sender parameter is the gesture recognizer.  Gesture recognizers have the `view` property which points to the view they're attached to.  So the image view that was tapped should be `sender.view` in that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for this type of task i generally use a UIButton over image view and addTarget to them and get image with button tag.

Comment: You haven't use UIButton to handle tap on image. It's overusing this component. Use tag, or just use `indexOfObject:` method to handle index of image.

Answer (score 3):

A better solution would be to use a `UITableView` or a `UICollectionView`, and listen to cell selection events...

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
for (NSArray *photo in self.photos) {
        imageName = [photo valueForKey:@"filename"];
        imageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
UIButton *starBtn  =   [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(imageX, imageY, imageSize, imageSize)];
        [starBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [starBtn setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [starBtn setTag:i+1];
        [starBtn setTitle:imageName forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [starBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor clearColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [starBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(goFullPhotoGallery:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:starBtn];
}
```

and goFullPhotoGallery function like this

```
-(void)goFullPhotoGallery:(UIButton *)imgView{
    NSString *imgName = imgView.titleLabel.text;
}
```